# JSON and Binary file in WPF

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I save a text file with JSON in WPF by the following code:

```
using (JsonWriter file = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter("Test.txt")))
{
   file.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
   file.WriteStartObject();
   file.WritePropertyName("TEST");
   file.WriteValue("test");
   file.WriteEndObject();
}
```

The file is saved in the following structure:

```
{
  "TEST": "test"
}
```

I want to save the file as binary file.

What I need to add / change in the code?

I have tried to use with a 'JsonSerializer' object and with the 'Serialize()' function instead of 'WriteValue()' function, but nothing changed.

I will be so happy to get a working sample code.

Thanks...

Comment: how is this related to WPF???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize the JSON in a binary format (such as BSON, or "Binary jSON") with JSON.NET, you can use the [`BsonWriter`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Bson_BsonWriter.htm#) class instead of the `JsonTextWriter`:

```
using (JsonWriter file = new Newtonsoft.Json.Bson.BsonWriter(new StreamWriter("Test.txt")))
{
   file.WriteStartObject();
   file.WritePropertyName("TEST");
   file.WriteValue("test");
   file.WriteEndObject();
}
```

You can also use the `JsonSerializer` class, again passing the `BsonWriter` instead of the `JsonTextWriter` to the `Serialize` methods.